# Python - MatPlotLib - How can I set two ticks on my x axis, one at the far left and one at the far right?

Tags: python, matplotlib

So I am trying to display some analytics in my python web-app. I want to display the date-time for the first and last entries on the x axis.

I have attempted to set the ticks as a two entry list but it gave a bad result.

```
plt.scatter(x_data, y_data)
    plt.grid(True)
    plt.xticks(x_data, [x_data[0], x_data[-1]])
    fig = plt.gcf()
```

Where the x_data is:

```
['10:59:44 27-03-2019', '11:00:07 27-03-2019', '11:00:09 27-03-2019', '11:00:12 27-03-2019', '11:30:23 27-03-2019', '11:30:29 27-03-2019', '11:30:30 27-03-2019', '11:30:31 27-03-2019', '11:30:32 27-03-2019', '11:32:44 27-03-2019', '11:33:21 27-03-2019', '11:35:50 27-03-2019', '12:16:12 27-03-2019', '12:16:39 27-03-2019', '12:17:36 27-03-2019', '12:19:40 27-03-2019', '12:23:50 27-03-2019']
```

I expected the output to place one on the far left and the other on the far right. Instead the first two ticks simply showed the times overlapping.

I am unsure what the proper way of doing it is.

Comment: have you tried `plt.xticks` without the second argument? for setting axis limits there is `plt.xlim` funtion

Comment: If I understand correctly you want all the ticks to show but only display the label for the first and last?

Comment: Yes, I do want the other ticks to show but for the first and last to be labelled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a workaround solution using some random data because you did not specify what the `y_data` is. The idea is to loop through the existing default tick labels and then replace all the tick labels by empty strings except the first and the last one.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

plt.scatter(x_data, range(len(x_data)))
plt.grid(True)

fig.canvas.draw()
xticks = ax.get_xticklabels()
labels_new = [lab.get_text() if i in [0, len(xticks)-1] else "" 
          for i, lab in enumerate(xticks) ]

ax.set_xticklabels(labels_new)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: It's a good workaround. If there is no official way then this will do. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I suspect your problem is that you are defining a vector of ticks and then assigning two labels (in position 0 and 1).

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x_data=np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8])
y_data=np.random.normal(0, 1, (8, 1))

# create an array for your labels 
new_labels=[''] * (len(x_data)-2)
new_labels.insert(0,x_data[0])
new_labels.append(x_data[-1])

plt.scatter(x_data, y_data)
plt.grid(True)
plt.xticks(x_data, new_labels) #use the new tick labels
fig = plt.gcf()
```

Comment: No this leads to an messed up output (http://oi65.tinypic.com/2j5qm9.jpg)

Comment: yes, of course. I added a list as second label =). Now it should work